# Responsive jQuery Datatable cannot get row data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have applied the responsive style to my jQuery Datatable using this [link](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). My table has got a edit/delete actions.

To perform edit/delete operations I am fetching row data this way.

```
var thisTr = $(this).parent().parent();
var rowData = table.row(thisTr).data();// table is actual $('#xyz').DataTable({});
```

Using this `rowData` I was fetching all my json values, but after making it responsive my `rowData` value in console is `undefined`

Below the console log of my table before zooming In
[image]
And after zooming in i.e., the responsive table style it rowData is undefined as shown below.
[image]

I realized that my code is a blooper and it doesn't work as table becomes responsive. Any pointers or tweaks would help.

Comment: What type of row data are you retrieving from the parent tr of the edit/delete button?

Comment: Row data will come as json Object.

Comment: With a normal edit or delete, you could attach the id of the item to edit/delete button itself and just use that id to send off in your click event to your handler to query the item and change it. This would be easier than grabbing some data off the row itself.

Comment: If your delete button appears in the child row after you reduce page width, `$(this).parent().parent();` will no longer give you `tr` node. Try `var thisTr = $(this).closest('tbody > tr');` instead.

Comment: This also isn't working.